# GraphQL Mutation - Syntax error expected "$", found "|"

Tags: graphql

I have the following mutation, however I keep getting an syntax invalid error:

```
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected "$", found "|".
```

The mutation itself looks like:

```
export const SUBSCRIPTION_MODIFY = gql`
  mutation($subName: String!, $returnUrl: String | URL) {
    appSubscriptionCreate(
        name: $subName
        returnUrl: $returnUrl
        test: true
      )
  }
`
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you create a type String | URL then just put that type as $return: newType?

Comment: But how would that syntax look, i.e. say I write: 
```const MYUNIONTYPE = gql`
union MyUnion = String | URL
` 
```
How do I pass in to the above mutation?

Comment: What GraphQL client are you using? See graphql custom scalar types.

Comment: no syntax for innline input type definition, **only input type name allowed**

Comment: it could be a return [query part] field param ... `...test:true) { id url(format: $returnFormat) otherMutationReturnedField }}`... or just param for mutation (string) resolver to define kind of sstring `url` returned (still missing return structure def)